# How to Install SQL CE 3.5 SP2 Silently

Tags: sql-server-ce

How to Install SQL CE 3.5 SP2 Silently...
  We are Using NullSoft.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two links should help you privately deploy SQLCE.  But a very brief overview is:

- Add the DLLs to your project so that they copy to your build folder
- Add the database factory entry to your app.config

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LinqAndSqlServerCe.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/22/privately-deploying-sql-server-compact-with-the-ado-net-entity-provider.aspx